# .htaccess redirect a folder if filename existing with the same name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Some servers creates subdomains folders in the same folder as main domain.

As a result if a main domain has news.php page rewritten to /news (just to remove php extension for SEO reasons) and /news folder existing at the same time, the user is being redirected to /news folder instead of news.php file.

I could redirect specific folders to a file with:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/plotki/?$ /plotki.php
```

but how to redirect all of them to the same filename as directory with some exception like /tags, /scripts etc. and all php files in main directory ?

Comment: Just as an FYI, there's no SEO reasons to remove a file extension. It looks nicer but won't rank any higher.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly: when a file exists in the main folder, you don't want a rewrite. However, if a folder is matched, it should also not rewrite to one file.

Lets assume you want all traffic to "index.php" but dont want the file "news.php" (which is in the main folder) nor the folder "/include/" to be redirected to index.php

The easiest way to do this, would be with a rewrite rule. For that you first need to turn on the `rewriteEngine` in the `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

The rewriteEngine works with conditions and rewrites. In your case there could be multiple contitions that should be met, prior to rewriting. If one of the conditions is not met, don't rewrite.

The below line tests if the "Request URI" contains the text "/include/". Only if it does NOT contain that in the url, it will let you continue to the next line and finally rewrite. You can place all exceptions like the below example. Note that you can use regular expression for this! `[NC]` means "No-case" [more info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/include/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/include/|/folder 2/|/folder[0-9]{2}) [NC]
```

After you place all exceptions as a rewrite condition, you want to make sure that if the file exists on the server, the rewrite rule does not apply. This is done with the line containing "!-f". Lastly you must make sure that the rewrite rule is not applied when the request URL already IS the index.php file (else you will get an internal, ethernal loop, and a 505 error). The final line sends all data to index.php. *Note that I do not send any additional parameters to index.php. In index.php you can read $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to obtain all data you need!*

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

You can use http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test your htaccess conditions. The script will tell if a condition is met or not. *Note that the website does not support all variables like `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`*

==Edit==

If you only want to redirect traffic to /page/... to page.php, but leave all other traffic as is you can make one more condition.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/include/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !page.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php [L]
```

`^/page/` means: ^ represents the beginning of the string, so, the Request URI must START with `/page/` in order to match the condition. If it does so, it will continue and rewrite that url to page.php

Comment: Almost good - exceptions are working, but I need something that will allow a redirection of /page to page.php not just index.php only if /page folder exists.

Comment: Correct me if i dont understand correctly: You only want the url /page/... being redirected to page.php? and all other trafic just as is? See edit above.

Comment: @MarekZakrzewski It's 2015 and you're trying to do mod_rewrites, instead of using a route system. It's like writing JavaScript code that supports IE 6

Comment: @dave As far as I'm aware, in 2015 mod_rewrite is theoretically still faster than routes. Also, routes require at least a part of the above mod_rewrite code to catch the traffic to one file. Even though routes is integrated in some frameworks, that does not mean that the OP uses a framework at all. Meaning that OP still needs to handle the request himself using the content of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and basically create his own "route system". Please do provide an answer if you think it might help OP.

Comment: page.php was just an example - what about random page ? If it founds an existing folder /xxx it would redirect to xxx.php.

Comment: im not sure what you want...? could you update the question with more info?